# Masspoint - curve - differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> On what curve in a vertical plane must a masspoint of mass m move, so that, with gravitational acceleration, it falls down with a constant vertical velocity $v_z=v_0=const.$? The initial values at $t=0$ are $x_0=y_0=z_0=0;~~v_x^0=0,~~v_y^0=w$.

First I tried drawing the situation and imagining possible curves on which the mass point could travel. I assume it's the y-z-plane and therefore I got this:

[image]

I tend to the drawn curve (2). But I am struggling to find an approach to this. I was thinking of just going with conservation of energy $E=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2-mgz$ and then solving for $\dot{x}$. But I kind of have trouble integrating it. Is that even the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bWe are moving in the $y$-$z$ plane, so $\vec{x}=(0,y,z)$, with $\dot z = v_{0}$ for all time.
By conservation of energy, $$\frac{1}{2}m(v_{0}^{2}+w^{2})=\frac{1}{2}m(v_{0}^{2}+\dot y^{2})-mgz$$
$$w^{2}=\dot y^{2}-2gz$$
Note that $\dot z=v_{0}$, so by the chain rule $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dz}v_{0}$. Hence $$w^{2}=v_{0}^{2}\left(\frac{dy}{dz}\right)^{2}-2gz$$
Therefore $$\frac{dy}{dz}=\pm\frac{1}{|v_{0}|}\sqrt{w^{2}+2gz}$$
Which looks solvable, unless I've made an algebra mistake. Good luck!

Comment: Two questions: Is $\dot{z}=v_0^2$ a typo? Second question: Does $\pm$ matter for the equation of $y$? Btw., thanks for the fast response. I mean like, incredibly fast. It took me like 2 hours to even get to an approach.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. As for the $\pm$, it looks like that just depends whether you choose $v_{0}$ to be positive or negative. so whether you're going up or down.

Comment: It's going down, so I guess $v_0$ is negative and therefore it's $-$, right?

Comment: I think so. Your particle's path has two forms depending on whether dy/dz is positive or negative. If it is positive, you take the positive root, and if it's negative you take the negative. Your solution switches form at a critical point, i.e. where the particle changes direction.